# Should features be correlated or uncorrelated for features-selection with the help of multiple regression analysis?

Tags: classification, regression, feature-selection, pearsons-correlation-coefficient

I have seen researchers using Pearson correlation coefficient to find out the relevant features -  to keep the features that have a high correlation value with the target. The implication is that the correlated features contribute more information in finding out the target in classification problems. Whereas, we remove the features which are redundant and have negligible correlation value.

Q1) Should highly correlated features with the target variable be included or removed from classification problems ? Is there a better/elegant explanation to this step?

Q2) How do we know that the dataset is linear when there are multiple variables involved? What does it mean by dataset being linear?

Q3) How to check for feature importance for non-linear case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Q1) Should highly correlated features with the target variable be included or removed from classification and regression problems? Is there a better/elegant explanation to this step?

Actually there's no strong reason either to keep or remove features which have a **low** correlation with the target response, other than reducing the number of features if necessary:

- It is correct that correlation is often used for feature selection. Feature selection is used for dimensionality reduction purposes, i.e. mostly to avoid overfitting due to having too many features / not enough instances (it's a bit more complex than this but that's the main idea). My point is that there's little to no reason to remove features if the number of features is not a problem, but if it is a problem then it makes sense to keep only the most informative features, and high correlation is an indicator of "informativeness" (information gain is another common measure to select features).
- In general feature selection methods based on measuring the contribution of **individual** features are used because they are very simple and don't require complex computations. However they are rarely optimal because they don't take into account the complementarity of groups of features together, something that most supervised algorithms can use very well. There are more advanced methods available which can take this into account: the most simple one is a brute-force method which consists in repeatedly measuring the performance (usually with cross-validation) with any possible subset of features... But that can take a lot of time for a large set of features.

However features which are highly correlated *together* (i.e. between features, not with the target response), should usually be removed because they are redundant and some algorithms don't deal very well with those. It's rarely done systematically though, because again this involves a lot of calculations.

> Q2) How do we know that the dataset is linear when there are multiple variable involved? What does it mean by dataset being linear?

It's true that correlation measures are based on linearity assumptions, but that's rarely the main issue: as mentioned above it's used as an easy indicator of "amount of information" and it's known to be imperfect anyway, so the linearity assumption is not so crucial here.

A dataset would be linear if the response variable can be expressed as a linear equation of the features (i.e. in theory one would obtain near-perfect performance with a linear regression).

> Q3) How to do feature importance for nonlinear case?

[Information gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio), [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), and probably a few other measures. But using these to select features **individually** is also imperfect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it really helped. Two last questions as a follow up -- (1) is feature reduction done after standardization or normalization or on the raw data set?(2) Often based on practice I noticed that for regression problem, if the target response is transformed to logarithm base 10, the fit is better. Why is that?

Comment: To be honest I'm not really sure about these two questions: (1) my intuition would be to standardize first, because this way the features selection takes into account the features exactly as they would be used. However I suspect that it doesn't matter too much, since standardization shouldn't change the correlation with the response variable too much. (2) I'm not sure if this is really common, it probably depends on the task, but I assume that the reason would be to convert from a non-linear relation to a (more) linear one: many problems are not linear but can be transformed into a linear one.

Comment: However features which are highly correlated together (i.e. between features, not with the target response), should usually be removed because they are redundant. This part of your Answer is incorrect. Correlated-ness is not a bad thing here - when you are classifying .

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar not sure what you mean? inter-correlated features is a problem for some algorithms (see e.g. [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-feature-correlation-matters-a-lot-847e8ba439c4))

Comment: correlated-ness between two features is useful in classifying and does not serve purpose of feature-selection (or removal of a feature).

Answer (score 3):

for feature engineering there are different methods.

**Pearson Correlation** comes under **Filter** methods. Filter methods gives intuition on the high level. This can be the first step for feature engineering. In this process

- the features having high correlation with target should be considered.
- the features having high correlation among themselves should also be removed as, "they are acting two independent variables doing same work" then why keep both.

After considering the correlation approaches you can also dig in to the **Wrapper** based methods which are more robust for feature selection but that includes the burden of training process.

Refer [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/12/introduction-to-feature-selection-methods-with-an-example-or-how-to-select-the-right-variables/) for introduction to the different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

1. A high Pearson correlation coefficient does not guarantee  a substantive relation of a feature with target variable. Evaluate it before inclusion in the model.                   2. Linear or nonlinear relationship needs an examination of individual variables. Some variables are likely  to have either a linear or nonlinear relationship with target  variable. Remaining variables may not have any relationship with target variable. 3. Checking for features importance does not need An examination of non-
   linearity or linearity.