# Hypothesis Testing and Independent variables Importance

Tags: machine-learning, python, statistics, data-science-model

I am learning Data Science and I have a confusion in one topic. I would like to describe my approach.

1. I have understood the problem statement.
2. I have used snowflake schema to join tables that have the attributes required for the job.
3. I have formulated the dataset.

Now, I am facing a question that how would I know which independent variables are actually significant for the problem. I got a hint that hypothesis testing procedures are used for determining the variable importance. Can someone please tell me that why do we use p-value, z-test, ANOVA test if we can easily find the correlation through the correlation-matrix in python?

Comment: Are you trying to make inferences about the population or are you trying to optimize predictions on unseen data?

Comment: Possibly related: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/63558/64377

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should features be correlated on uncorrelated for classification and regression (prediction)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/63558/should-features-be-correlated-on-uncorrelated-for-classification-and-regression)

Comment: snowflake schema to join tables is not clear to me.